# Como centralizar os elementos dentro de uma div?

Tags: html, css, div

Estou tentando alinhar os elementos que são três círculos com suas respectivas descrições dentro da minha `div` ao centro usando a seguinte classe:

```
.center {
    margin:auto;    
}
```

No entanto, não obtive sucesso desta forma, fica tudo a esquerda. Esses sãos os elementos que eu gostaria de alinhar:

```css
.ligado {
    background: yellow;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.desligado {
    background: gray;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.center {
    margin:auto;    
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div id="1" class="ligado"></div>  
  <p>Quarto</p>
  
  <div id="2" class="desligado"></div>
  <p>Cozinha</p>
  
  <div id="3" class="ligado"></div>
  <p>Sala de estar</p>
</div>
```

Como eu poderia centralizar os elementos dentro da `div`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.ligado {
    background: yellow;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto; //adicionado
}

.desligado {
    background: gray;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto; //adicionado
}

.center {
    // modificado
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div id="1" class="ligado"></div>  
  <p>Quarto</p>
  
  <div id="2" class="desligado"></div>
  <p>Cozinha</p>
  
  <div id="3" class="ligado"></div>
  <p>Sala de estar</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Resolveu meu problema

Answer (score 2):

Eu ia descartar essa resposta pois fiquei na dúvida se o `<div>` também tinha que ficar ou não centralizado na página. Mas acabei deixando da mesma forma que na pergunta, espero que seja o que precisa.

Única coisa que mudei no seletor `.center` foi um fundo bege para destacar o próprio `<div>`, usei um [`display: table`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/display) e alinhei o texto ao centro [`text-align: center;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/text-align).

Aos seletores `.ligado` e `.desligado` adicionei [`margin: auto;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/margin) para centralizar os elementos.

```css
.ligado {
  background: yellow;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

.desligado {
  background: gray;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

.center {
  background: beige;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div id="1" class="ligado"></div>
  <p>Quarto</p>

  <div id="2" class="desligado"></div>
  <p>Cozinha</p>

  <div id="3" class="ligado"></div>
  <p>Sala de estar</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

### Vejamos...

Vou expor uma **alternativa** à resposta do @guilherme-henriques que usa do conceito dos *flexbox* do CSS 3. Esta alternativa também se alinha mais com seu modo de centralizar.

Antes do CSS 3, era o modo "padrão". Hoje não é *mainstream* ou *cool*. Coisas da moda..

---

### Centralizando um `<div>`

Um `<div>`, para ser centralizado, deve ter um **tamanho definido** em relação a horizontal (largura). Suas **margens** devem estar configuradas para serem **automáticas**. Exemplo:

```css
#fundo { 

  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  
  background-color: #c33; 
  
  }
  
#exemplo {

  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;

  }
```

```html
<div id="fundo">
  <br />
  <div id="exemplo">&lt;div&gt; centralizado horizontalmente</div>
</div>
```

Note que isto não centraliza os elementos internos do `<div>`. Entretanto, este ainda será referência para os elementos internos a ele - incluindo outros elementos `<div>`. Assim:

- Os elementos internos de um `<div>` pai não são centralizados ao centralizar o `<div>` pai. Precisam ser centralizados independentemente seguindo as regras já expostas: *tamanho definido* e *margem automática*.
- Para textos e imagens, você deve usar o *alinhamento de texto* (`text-align: center`).

O tamanho de um `<div>` pai deve ser **maior que o dos elementos internos** para que se possa observar o fenômeno da centralização horizontal. Se forem de tamanhos iguais (e.g `width: 100%;` em elementos pai e filho), a centralização ocorre *porém* sem que se possa observar visualmente. Estarão sobrepostos.

Veja o exemplo a seguir. Note que diferenciei as alturas para que se se observe a centralização e a sobreposição.

```css
#fundo { 

  height: 100px;
  
  background-color: #c33; 
  
  }
  
#exemplo {

  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;

  }
```

```html
<div id="fundo">
  <br />
  <div id="exemplo">&lt;div&gt; centralizado horizontalmente</div>
</div>
```

Na maioria dos casos da vida real, um programador sem experiência (ou mesmo sem base teórica forte) poderia supor que nada ocorreu. Fundos idênticos quanto a cor e alturas idênticas corroboram para a premissa errada. É um *erro comum*.

Assim, considere utilizar `margin: auto;` em todos os elementos `<div>` que deseja centralizar dentro do elemento pai. Pode ser individualmente:

```
.desligado {
    ...
    margin: auto;
}

.ligado {
    ...
    margin: auto;
}
```

... Ou geral:

```
.center > div { // ">" indica elementos-filho (descendente direto)
    margin: auto;
}
```

### Exemplo funcional

Segue seu código de forma funcional. Repare que `.center` foi usado apenas para florear e tornar visual a observância do fenômeno.

```css
.ligado {
  background: yellow;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.desligado {
  background: gray;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;     /* centraliza o texto */
  background-color: #eee; /* fornece cor ao fundo para melhor visualizar */
  padding: 2em;           /* 'desgrudado' das bordas do div-pai */
}

.center > div { /* centraliza os elementos 'div' dentro do 'div.center' */
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">

  <div id="1" class="ligado"></div>  
  <p>Quarto</p>

  <div id="2" class="desligado"></div>
  <p>Cozinha</p>

  <div id="3" class="ligado"></div>
  <p>Sala de estar</p>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Tanto o elemento `div` quanto o elemento `p` são elementos de bloco, logo colocando `margin: auto` na div pai `.center` não irá alinhá-los ao centro. É preciso usar um seletor que irá alinhar tudo ao centro:

```
.center > *{
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

O código acima irá aplicar `margin: auto` a todos os elementos de bloco com largura fixa, centralizando-os, e também os seus textos internos.

```css
.ligado {
    background: yellow;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.desligado {
    background: gray;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.center > * {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div id="1" class="ligado"></div>  
  <p>Quarto</p>
  
  <div id="2" class="desligado"></div>
  <p>Cozinha</p>
  
  <div id="3" class="ligado"></div>
  <p>Sala de estar</p>
</div>
```